# Where to store php files used for an Ajax request in a custom component

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery, ajax

Where should I put the php files that I will be using to perform Ajax requests in my custom component? for example I need to populate a certain dropdown list based on an input? The php file that i will be using will return the html formatted data that will be put to a dropdown list.

Comment: You keep your files in in the directory belonging to the extension you wish to integrate Ajax

Comment: I will use it in my custom component. Where will i put it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are building **component** , then it is best to write in your **component's controllers** file and for **module** write in **helper file** and use [com_ajax](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface)

Comment: Do you mean I should write the function I need to the custom component's controller file? or in my component's controllers folder, i will create a php file in there?

Comment: yes, can't we do that? create a function which will create drop down html markup in a related controller file (job you are trying to achieve). call it from ajax url get the response and update the required section in DOM

Comment: I will try. Thanks for your response. I am completely new to Ajax refresh.